# Validating an infix expression

Tags: validation, infix-notation

I'm trying to validate infix expressions.

So far, I've developed code that can detect a large percentage of invalid infix expressions, but for some reason, the case "( ( ( ) ) ) 5"  is not detected as invalid.

How do I detect the invalid condition when there are parenthesis that have no expression?

Comment: By fixing your code of course. If this answer isn't enough, you probably should add more details to the question.

Comment: Show some code and I'm sure we can help. Different people use different techniques for compiling/interpreting infix expressions. So you'll need to be more specific. Narrow your question to something like: "Why doesn't this code catch this invalid expression?"

Comment: If you're using the typical depth-increment/decrement approach, then you're probably back at depth zero when the 5 is encountered, hence making it look valid.  If so, you'd need to detect when the depth is increased and immediately decreased without a symbol in between. Of course, this entirely depends on your code... and in the intervening two years, you've probably fixed it :-)